# CakePHP find / paginate with hasMany Field as implode()

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I have two models `Model A` and `Model B`. `Model A` hasMany `Model B`.

So now I want to build a paginated table in a View about `Model A`. And there I want a column, where a specific field of `Model B` is shown as comma separated list.

Imagine `Model A` is named `Group` and `Model B` is named `User`.

`Group hasMany User`

Now I want a table of the groups like

id | name | user

1 | first group | User 1, User 2, User 3

But I don´t want to use a foreach within the View, it should be a string already in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Model::afterFind() callback](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#afterfind) and build the string in your model and add it to the result set. In the view just use it like echo h($result['Model']['your_field_list']).